# Tornado current_user gets create twice instead of once

Tags: python, cookies, tornado, peewee

I am trying to make a simple website where you don't have to sign up. Instead I create a session cookie immediately after a user loads a page.

```
def get_current_user(self):
    auth_id = self.get_secure_cookie('auth_id')
    if not auth_id:
        session_id = uuid.uuid4()
        auth = Auth.create(session=session_id)
        self.set_secure_cookie('auth_id', str(auth.id))
    else:
        try:
            auth = Auth.select().where(Auth.id == auth_id).get()
        except Auth.DoesNotExist:
            session_id = uuid.uuid4()
            auth = Auth.create(session=session_id)
            self.set_secure_cookie('auth_id', str(auth.id))

    return auth
```

The problem is that when a user refreshes the page a new session cookie is being created. And after that everything works perfectly (no new cookies).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you checked the DB to ensure the entry in the `auth` table exists?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but could it possibly the request to get the page's favicon that's causing the issue?